# How to pass a class object to a function but prevent mutation?

Tags: swift

I can't see where in the Swift language is the facility to pass a class object to a function yet prevent that function from mutating the object by either calling functions that will implicitly mutate it or setting public variables. I'm gathering that this facility just does not exist, can anyone confirm?

That is to say, all objects are always mutable everywhere they can be seen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is extremely common throughout Cocoa. You create an immutable class and a mutable subclass. For examples, see AVComposition/AVMutableComposition, CBService/CBMutableService, CNContact/CNMutableContact.

In ObjC, this is common practice with collections as well (arrays, dictionaries, etc), but since those are value types in Swift, there's no need to use the classes (NSArray/NSMutableArray).

In Swift, rather than creating two classes, you create an immutable protocol and a class:

```
protocol Person: AnyObject {
    var name: String { get }
    var address: String { get }
}

class MutablePerson: Person {
    var name: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
}
```

Now, any function that accept `Person` will have an immutable object, and any function that accepts `MutablePerson` will be able to mutate it. This is a general pattern you can use to give different parts of your program access to different slices of the object's API. It's much more general and flexible than just `const`.

That said, this is not as common a pattern in Swift as it is in ObjC, since in most cases where this is useful, the type should be a struct anyway. But it is absolutely available if needed.

---

To your question about doing this with two classes, as in ObjC, it's possible, as long as you define both in the same file. It's just a bit tedious:

```
public class Person {
    public fileprivate(set) var name: String = ""
    public fileprivate(set) var address: String = ""
}

public class MutablePerson: Person {
    public override var name: String {
        get { super.name }
        set { super.name = newValue }
    }
    public override var address: String {
        get { super.address }
        set { super.address = newValue }
    }
}
```

It's possible a property wrapper could improve this, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: Nice, thanks. As a matter of curiousity, couldn't this also be done in Swift with subclasses instead of protocols, like with ObjC?

Comment: Yes, but it's somewhat tedious. Property wrappers might be able to fix that, but I'm not sure if property wrappers can be made `fileprivate`.

Comment: I think my `Immutable` completely covers properties, right? I don't think it can be a property wrapper, because allowing access to the object will open it up for mutation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way I can think of to allow usage of methods, but properties are no problem**. Just use an `Immutable` as a function parameter.

```swift
final class Class {
  var property = true
}

var object = Immutable(Class())
object.property = false // Cannot assign to property: 'object' is immutable
```

```swift
/// An affordance for accessing the properties of an object
/// without the ability to mutate them.
@dynamicMemberLookup
public struct Immutable<Object: AnyObject> {
  private let object: Object
}

// MARK: - public
public extension Immutable {
  init(_ object: Object) {
    self.object = object
  }

  subscript<Value>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<Object, Value>) -> Value {
    object[keyPath: keyPath]
  }
}
```

** The getters *could* be mutating, and they *could* return mutating closures.  But that's an issue with the protocol approach as well. The best that we can do right now is a generally accurate hack.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for are value types (such as `struct`s). If you mutate any properties of a value type, you mutate the instance itself.

This means that when you pass a value type to a function, the function won't be able to mutate any of the properties of said value type.

On the other hand, `class`es are reference types, so mutating any of their properties doesn't mutate the class instance itself. Because of this, you cannot ban functions from modifying mutable properties of the class (unless you make them setter of said properties private).

Comment: Well I'm specifically asking about classes, so no, what I am looking for is *not* a struct, but your comment might be useful for other readers. Classes have functionality that structs do not, and I was hoping there was a way to restrict mutation despite having those features, i.e. what you can do in C++ or some other languages regarding when to allow mutation.

Comment: @johnbakers I did answer that part of the question as well - the only possibility is to use `private(set)` on all properties that you don't want to be modified outside the class. However, there is NO way at all to restrict functions from modifying properties of an input argument if that argument is a `class`.

Comment: it's a shame; it would be very useful and remove some classes of errors to say "this class is read-only in this scope" while still of course allowing the class to change over time. Many functions will need to see the contents of a class but not need to modify it, while others may need to update it appropriately, and it's too bad the language does not make this distinction and intent possible.